# SimpleBeanEditorDriver does not work for Checkbox in GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder, gwt2

I am using `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` for a gwt form submit .

Form contains widgets like `TextBox`,`DropDown` and `CheckBox` .

While clicking on submit button I can get my populated Object as below inside submit button event method ,

```
Employee emp = driver.flush();
```

My problem is I can get all the values entered from `TextBox` and `Dropdown` , but `Checkbox` value is always populated as false for the boolean balue that is mapped to my Bean.

Its quite strange as only `Checkbox` value is not submitting .

Could you please help me with this,as I can not find any solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your bean? Does it use `boolean` (primitive type) or `Boolean` (object) ?

Comment: My Bean uses boolean(primitive) type. After reading your comment I tried with Boolean(Object)  and it worked. Could you please let me know the reason ?